# Autocorrelation function for deterministic nonlinear dynamical systems

Tags: fourier-transform, spectroscopy, oscillators, non-linear-systems

I am quite puzzled with the problem that spectral analysis has been either applied to noisy dynamical systems or to chaotic ones. I was wondering why nobody makes analysis of non-linear dynamical systems based on their autocorrelation? At least for non-linear oscillators which are essentially periodic and seem to suit for such analyses.

For example I simulated Van der Pol oscillator for 500 seconds from initial condition $(1.1,0.1)$. The 2D ODE is as follows:
$$
\frac{d\textbf{x}}{dt}=
\begin{cases}
\mu(x_0-1/3 x_0^3-x_1)\\
\frac{x_0}{\mu}
\end{cases}
$$
Where I have set the $\mu$ to $5$. The plot of the oscillator and the autocorrelation function as defined by Wiener are as follows:
[image]
[image]

Sorry for the lack of labels. The $x$-label in the second plot is representing lag in seconds and the $y$ axis is $C(\tau)=\frac{1}{T}\lim\limits_{T\to \infty}\int^T_{-T}x_0(t)x_0(t+\tau)dt$.

What would be wrong with such analysis when the autocorrelation function exists? Is this a totally dumb question??

Comment: The autocorrelation you show looks a bit weird to me. I would expect it to be maximum at $\tau=0$ (by definition) and periodic with the same period of your $x$. Also, didn't you mean to write $\dfrac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}$ in your equation?

Comment: @Bernhard, you are completely right. My mistake. I made the corrections.

Comment: The main problem with a linear quantity like autocorrelation applied to a non-linear system is, that  the autocorrelation function would depend on the amplitude (more generally the total energy) of the system. You wouldn't end up with one graph, but with an infinite set of them that is parametrized by the energy of the system. What are you going to do with that in general? In special cases, e.g. to separate chaotic from non-chaotic regions, it could be a useful way of looking at the system, but I am not sure that it would be more useful than e.g. Lyapunov exponents, limit cycles etc..

Comment: @CuriousOne The existence of such functions would rather rely on ergodicity of the system and that is independent of the system being linear or non-linear and there are quite a lot of nonlinear system who have constant levels of energy I believe; indeed my main argument was about self sustained oscillators and  limit cycles. Maybe I forgot to point that out. And I wonder why such measure is not used these analysis?

Regarding your linear argument I should say, is that anything different in nature for correlation integral in being linear? But it is one of the main tools for chaos theory, right?

Comment: @Cupitor: I was (implicitly) talking about ergodic systems when I mentioned energy as a parameter. I was also assuming, that the system is behaved well enough, that the integral of the autocorrelation function converges everywhere. But even then one won't get the same autocorrelation for all energies for non-linear systems. That the autocorrelation function is a simple function, rather than a parametrized set of functions for linear systems is a direct consequence of their linearity. I don't remember autocorrelation to be useful for the study of chaos (my last lecture was 25 years ago...).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a problem following your argument; the energy of the system I believe is the integral for $C(t)$ (as I wrote the expression for) when the lag zero. In the case of a nonlinear osicllator I assume that is constant and is fixed for any limit cycle that has a fixed model. 

I was not referring to autocorrelation but correlation integral:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_integral
Its different from autocorrelation but the statistics is still linear in the same sense that you call autocorrelation linear.

Comment: I am missing what actual analysis you want to perform. So far, you plotted the autocorrelation function. What insights do you want to gain from it?

Comment: I didn't take a step further which was Fourier analysis of autocorrelation function. The reason that I need to work with spectrum is irrelevant here, but what I was trying to understand was the reason that why these types of dynamical systems are never studied with such toolkit but the same toolkit has been used for the study of chaotic systems and also signal-plus-noise systems... I am trying to understand what will be inherently wrong with this...

Comment: @Cupitor - Are you working with data or simulation/theory?  If data, then it is probably not very useful to use the autocorrelation for many things.  It can be useful for pattern matching (e.g., find wave modes in time series that have a specific appearance).  However, as CuriousOne said, the possible dependence on the amplitude of the signal will make interpretation of the results all but impossible.  I suppose it is possible to do such analysis, but whether it would yield anything physically significant is another question.

Comment: **Caveat:**  In my second sentence, I was implying for nonlinear systems.  I was not trying to say that autocorrelation is rarely useful for data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specific context that you may be looking for, but it's quite common to use a four-point correlation function of the quantum dipole moment operator to retrieve non-linear relaxation dynamics.  These correlation functions make up the nonlinear response function of a material system to an electric field which, when convolved with the excitation spectrum yield an experimentally accessible nonlinear polarization.  For some examples, look into pump probe or 2D spectroscopy as well as Mukamel's Principles of Nonlinear Optical Spectroscopy.

Hope this is useful, or relevant to what you're looking for.